# Why does my bootstrap 2x2 column not line up with my 1x4 column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mockup here

http://jsfiddle.net/gNF4M/

On the top half I have 4 offset and a 1x4 column.  On the bottom half I have 4 offset and 2x2 columns.  According to the grid system these should line up perfectly however visually it appears that the bottom half is 'squashed'.  Is there something wrong with the settings that I have used?  Click if but the if the the the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hero-unit" class you're using is making the top part wider than span4, probably because of its 60px padding